# Do any proxies translate authentication from form-based to basic?

Tags: authentication, proxy

I'm looking to use a search indexer on several intranet sites.  A challenge I face is that the sites use form-based authentication, and the indexer is limited to basic/digest/ntlm authentication.  It's the same name and password either way, so I'm wondering if there's any sort of proxy or proxy plugin that presents basic authentication to the user when the website it is proxying presents an authentication form, and submits the webform using the credentials scraped from the basic auth?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?  I'm facing the same issue trying to get a crawler (Heritrix or Nutch) to use a tricky, form-based, POST authentication on an intranet.